# Cocoa Touch equivalent of JavaScript's focus/blur

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In JavaScript there's a concept of focusing and blurring input elements. Is there something similar in Cocoa Touch? I want to fire some action when user ends editing of one textfield and goes to the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make

```
[UITextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

to focus the Text Field.
when the User is finished with his input, he propably uses the "next" button provided by the keyboard, in which case you should use delegates to get from one Field to another